# input type hidden checkbox cheked js

Tags: javascript

Имеется код `<input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" name="array[]">`
Дело в том, что данный чекбокс всегда находится в состоянии display: none;
а эмуляция чекбокса происходит через jquery, тобишь `<div></div>` имеет статус активности `<div class="checked"></div>`
Как при событии `on('click')` в массив `array[]` заносить value="" выбранных чекбоксов? при условии что `input type checkbox` всегда в `display none?`

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, что понял до конца, но думаю, что стоит произвести рефакторинг задачи и кода. Однако вот вариант на vanilla:

```js
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick=function(){
  //установить класс для дива
  var div=document.getElementById("thatdiv").className = "checked"; 
  //создать пустой массив для данных
  var variable = new Array();
  //выбрать все включенные чекбоксы внутри элемента с классом checked
  var chkd=document.querySelectorAll('.checked input:checked');
  //пройти через все элементы, выбранные на предыдущем шаге
  for (var i=0; i<chkd.length; i++){
    //последовательно записать в массив все значения value каждого элемента
    variable.push(chkd[i].getAttribute("value"));
                                    }
  //если ни один чекбокс не включен
  if(chkd.length==0)
  {//вывести информацию в p#info
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML='Перед нажатием на кнопку выделите checkbox!';}
  else
  {
    //вывести в консоль значения в памяти
    console.log(variable);
    //установить значение value элемента array
    document.getElementById('array').value=JSON.stringify(variable);
    //вывести значение value элемента array
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML='Успешно. Значение checkbox#array ='+document.getElementById('array').value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="thatdiv">
   <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" id="array">
   <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="a1">Windows 95/98<Br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="a2">Windows 2000<Br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="a3">System X<Br> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="a4">Linux<Br> 
  </p>
  </div>

    <p><a id="clickme">кликать сюда</a></p>
    <p id="info"></p>
```

тоже самое с использованием jquery

```js
$("#clickme").click(function(){
  //установить класс для дива
  $("#thatdiv").addClass( "checked" );
  //создать пустой массив для данных
  var variable = new Array();
  //выбрать все включенные чекбоксы внутри элемента с классом checked,пройти через все и добавить в массив
  
  $( ".checked input:checked" ).each(function() {
    variable.push($( this ).val());
    });

  //если ни один чекбокс не включен
  if($( ".checked input:checked" ).length==0)
  {//вывести информацию в p#info
    $("#info").html('Перед нажатием на кнопку выделите checkbox!');}
  else
  {
    //вывести в консоль значения в памяти
    console.log(variable);
    //установить значение value элемента array
    $("#array").val(JSON.stringify(variable));
    //вывести значение value элемента array
    $("#info").html('Успешно. Значение checkbox#array ='+$("#array").val());

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thatdiv">
   <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" id="array">
   <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="a1">Windows 95/98<Br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="a2">Windows 2000<Br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="a3">System X<Br> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="a4">Linux<Br> 
  </p>
  </div>

    <p><a id="clickme">кликать сюда</a></p>
    <p id="info"></p>
```

Также, в случае необходимости var variable = new Array(); можно вынести перед функцией, тогда обращение будет к глобальному массиву и значения будут храниться в памяти (если это действительно нужно).

Comment: Ну лейблы же...

Comment: @Qwertiy , лень было самому инпуты набирать, дернул с первой ссылки гугла :)

Answer (score -1):

`display: none` влияет на работоспособность только в IE8.

Если IE8 не поддерживается, то так же, как для всех остальных чекбоксов.

Если поддерживается, заменять на `position: absolute;` с дополнительными фокусами, чтобы спрятать чекбокс. Точно не помню, подходит ли `visibility: hidden`.